# Float - datatype confusion

Tags: java, floating-point

```
class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] arg2) 
    {
        float num = 1234.123126f;
        System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

Output: 1234.1232
Why it is not 1234.123 or 1234.1231?

Comment: The exact value of `num` is actually 1234.1231689453125. println displays the shortest unique number that identifies this value, rounded, which in this case is 1234.1232. In other words, "1234.1232 is the closest number to the actual value that can be expressed with 8 digits." Give http://floating-point-gui.de a read for more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.out.println(float)` calls `String.valueOf(float)`, which calls `Float.toString(float)`.

The answer is in the documentation for [`Float.toString(float)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#toString(float)):

> How many digits must be printed for the fractional part of `m` or `a`? There must be at least one digit to represent the fractional part, and beyond that as many, but only as many, more digits as are needed to uniquely distinguish the argument value from adjacent values of type float.

Therefore, it printed `1234.1232` because it is the closest value representable by the `float` data-type that is uniquely identifiable from any adjacent `float` values.

Comment: It turns out [Java doesn't always print the shortest string that round-trips](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-doesnt-print-the-shortest-strings-that-round-trip/).

Answer (score 0):

I see your point. Your rounding logic is correct. But, since you're using a `float` datatype, you will be losing some amount of precision. So, when the JVM does the rounding, it is arriving at the value of 1234.1232.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because of rounding of the exact value. If you want to print the exact value as it is, you will have to specify the format using examples given in this [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [a float can only reliably store up to 6 digits](http://www.exploringbinary.com/decimal-precision-of-binary-floating-point-numbers/); 1234.123126 is too long to store as a float and recover as a decimal exactly.

Java prints a decimal string that allows you to recover the internal float value. In the worst case, 9 decimal digits are required, but less can suffice. The internal float value of 1234.123126 is 1234.1231689453125. Rounded to 9 digits, that's 1234.12317. But 1234.1232 converts to the same float, and is shorter, so Java chooses that. (Note that 1234.123 and 1234.1231 are incorrect choices, since they [convert to](http://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/) a different float: 1234.123046875.